# How to convert a unix epoch to highly accurate timestamp [pandas]?

Tags: pandas, datetime, timestamp, time-series

I have a time series with unix epoch that I want to convert to time with format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f'.

When I use

```
   pd.to_datetime(data['Time'],format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
```

I get dates around 1970-01-01 00:23:03.270 which is not correct (as the real time of my data is around 2013-11-01)
and when I try

```
   pd.to_datetime(data['Time'],unit='ms')
```

I have the correct dates, but I do not have the nano precision. On the other hand, when I combine unit and format such as

```
   pd.to_datetime(data['Time'],unit='ms',format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
```

I get a code error that says 'cannot specify both format and unit'.

Do you know how to fix such problem?

Comment: Try `pd.to_datetime(data['Time'], unit='s')` instead?

Comment: Error: cannot convert 1383260000000.0 with the unit 's'

Comment: What does your `Time` column look like? Please post the output of this `data['Time'].head()`

Comment: it looks like this  Float64Index([1383260000000.0, 1383260000000.0, 1383260000000.0,
              1383260000000.0, 1383260000000.0, 1383260000000.0,
              1383260000000.0, 1383260000000.0, 1383260000000.0,
              1383260000000.0,
              ...
              1383340000000.0, 1383340000000.0, 1383340000000.0,
              1383340000000.0, 1383340000000.0, 1383340000000.0,
              1383340000000.0, 1383340000000.0, 1383340000000.0,
              1383340000000.0],
             dtype='float64', name='Time', length=1048576)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some of your sample data as a dataframe called `df`:

```
            Time
0   1.383260e+12
1   1.383260e+12
2   1.383260e+12
3   1.383260e+12
4   1.383260e+12
5   1.383260e+12
6   1.383260e+12
7   1.383260e+12
8   1.383260e+12
9   1.383260e+12
10  1.383340e+12
11  1.383340e+12
12  1.383340e+12
13  1.383340e+12
14  1.383340e+12
15  1.383340e+12
16  1.383340e+12
17  1.383340e+12
18  1.383340e+12
19  1.383340e+12
```

Convert to a `datetime` object then set your desired format:

`pd.to_datetime(df.Time, unit='ms').dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')`

This gives:

```
0     2013-10-31 22:53:20.000000
1     2013-10-31 22:53:20.000000
2     2013-10-31 22:53:20.000000
3     2013-10-31 22:53:20.000000
4     2013-10-31 22:53:20.000000
5     2013-10-31 22:53:20.000000
6     2013-10-31 22:53:20.000000
7     2013-10-31 22:53:20.000000
8     2013-10-31 22:53:20.000000
9     2013-10-31 22:53:20.000000
10    2013-11-01 21:06:40.000000
11    2013-11-01 21:06:40.000000
12    2013-11-01 21:06:40.000000
13    2013-11-01 21:06:40.000000
14    2013-11-01 21:06:40.000000
15    2013-11-01 21:06:40.000000
16    2013-11-01 21:06:40.000000
17    2013-11-01 21:06:40.000000
18    2013-11-01 21:06:40.000000
19    2013-11-01 21:06:40.000000
```

Answer (score 0):

Tried in combination with `astype`?

`pd.to_datetime(data['time'].astype(float)/1e9, unit='ms')`

Comment: it provides the required accuracy but still give the wrong dates (1970-01-01)